# Programmatically run WPF event handler

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two following events for wpf datagrid:

1-CellEditEnding

2-PreviewKeyDown

When I finish editing in any of the cell in datagrid, first PreviewKeyDown event runs and then CellEditEnding. But I need to run CellEditEnding first and then PreviewKeyDown. So i was calling PreviewKeydown event programmatically in the CellEditEnding event by writing the following code.

```
private void maingrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox t = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
    DataGridColumn dgc = e.Column;
    if ((string)dgc.Header == "Product Id")
    {
        if (vm_order.PopulateProductRow(maingrid.SelectedIndex, Convert.ToInt32(t.Text)) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Product does not exists           ", "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
    }

    **maingrid.PreviewKeyDown += new maingrid_PreviewKeyDown(maingrid_PreviewKeyDown);**
}
```

Please view the last line of code where i am calling PrevewKeyDownEvent programmatically which is giving error.

I have seen an example for mouse_up event for wpf datagrid which is working very nicely. Following is the code for reference:

```
public EventsSample()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pnlMainGrid.MouseUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(pnlMainGrid_MouseUp);
}

private void pnlMainGrid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked me at " + e.GetPosition(this).ToString());
}
```

So why cannot I use this for PreviewKeyDown event?

Comment: Did you look at KeyDownEvent instead of PreviewKeyDown? Preview prefix mean that such type of events must leading

Comment: in _list line of code_ you **not only** call `PrevewKeyDownEvent` handler, but also try create object from it, and add again as event. so possibly you need just `maingrid_PreviewKeyDown(sender, new KeyEventArgs())`

Comment: I have edit my question. Please view the second example which is working fine.I want to to this exactly same for PreviewKeyDown or KeyDown events for wpd datagrid, thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues. First there is a syntax error in line
`maingrid.PreviewKeyDown += new maingrid_PreviewKeyDown(maingrid_PreviewKeyDown);`
That is incorrect. `maingrid_PreviewKeyDown` is the name of a method and you cannot "new-up" a method. That is the reason you get a compiler error. The correct way to subscribe to an event is:
`mainGrid.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(mainGrid_PreviewKeyDown);`

Look at your own code for the MouseUp event. This form is consistent with the way your own code subscribes to the mouse event. Note however that this is a very old syntax. Since C# 2 or maybe C# 3 we have a simpler form. You could write:
`mainGrid.PreviewKeyDown += mainGrid_PreviewKeyDown;`
and
`pnlMainGrid.MouseUp += pnlMainGrid_MouseUp;`

You have however a bigger problem. I am going to copy your code here using the corrected syntax and then try to explain what that the bigger problem is:

```
01  private void maingrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
02  {
03      TextBox t = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
04      DataGridColumn dgc = e.Column;
05      if ((string)dgc.Header == "Product Id")
06      {
07          if (vm_order.PopulateProductRow(maingrid.SelectedIndex, Convert.ToInt32(t.Text)) == false)
08          {
09              MessageBox.Show("Product does not exists           ", "Message", MessageBoxButton.OK);
10          }
11      }
12
13      mainGrid.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(mainGrid_PreviewKeyDown);
14  }
```

In line 13:
`mainGrid.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(mainGrid_PreviewKeyDown);`
You are not calling the event handler. You are only subscribing to the event. In other words, you are telling the system that the next time the event `PreviewKeyDown` will be raised, you want the method `mainGrid_PreviewKeyDown` to be called. What this means is that the first time `maingrid_CellEditEnding` is called, you are subscribing to `PreviewKeyDown`. Next time `maingrid_CellEditEnding` is called you are subscribing again to `PreviewKeyDown`. At this point you have two events handlers (that happen to be the same method) associated with the event `PreviewKeyDown`. When `PreviewKeyDown` is raised next time, `mainGrid_PreviewKeyDown` will be called twice for the same event. After `CellEditEnding` is raised let's say 10 times, `maingrid_CellEditEnding` will have been called 10 times. The event `PreviewKeyDown` will also have been subscribed 10 times. At this point, the next time `PreviewKeyDown` will be raised, its event handler – that is method `mainGrid_PreviewKeyDown` will be called 10 times for the same event.

To see this in action I suggest that as a test you implement `mainGrid_PreviewKeyDown` this way:

```
void mainGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("mainGrid_PreviewKeyDown was called");
}
```

Run your application and keep an eye on the Visual Studio debug output.
Note: To show the debug output window go to [menu / DEBUG / Windows / Output].

To address this problem you have several options:

**Option 1**
This will only work if in your method `mainGrid_PreviewKeyDown` you do not use the information contained in parameter `object sender` or `KeyEventArgs e`. If that is the case do the following:

- No longer subscribe to the `PreviewKeyDown` event.
- Rewrite `maingrid_CellEditEnding` so that at the end of the method you perform the actions you would normally perform in your `mainGrid_PreviewKeyDown`. This way you will execute the actions in the order you need.

**Option 2**
If you do need the information contained in parameters `object sender` or `KeyEventArgs e'.

- Subscribe to both `CellEditEnding` and `PreviewKeyDown` events.
- When the handler for `PreviewKeyDown` is called, don’t do anything just yet, only store in some fields the information from `KeyEventArgs` that you will need later.
- When the handler for `CellEditEnding` is called, then do whatever you do to handle `CellEditEnding`. When that is done, use the information you stored earlier about `KeyEventArgs` to do whatever you need regarding the PreviewKeyDown event.

**Option 3**
Find other events to subscribe to that have the order that you like.

Comment: I have edit my question. Please view the second example which is working fine.I want to to this exactly same for PreviewKeyDown or KeyDown events for wpd datagrid, thanks,